# Live checking value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have a textarea that have a id upload-message. And this jvavscript:

```
 // step-2 happens in the browser dialog
            $('#upload-message').change(function() {
                $('.step-3').removeClass('error');
                $('.details').removeClass('error');
            });
```

But how can i check this live? Now, i type in the upload message textarea. And go out of the textarea. Than the jquery function is fired. But how can i do this live?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "live"? On every keypress?

Comment: What do you mean live? As you type?

Comment: You probably want to use `.keyup` or `.keydown` events rather than the `.change` for realtime action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`.keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/):

```
$('#upload-message').keyup(function() {
    $('.step-3, .details').removeClass('error');
});
```

However, this'll keep on running for every keypress, which in the case you provided does not make sense.

You should rather bind it once with [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('#upload-message').one('keyup', function() {
    $('.step-3, .details').removeClass('error');
});
```

...so that this event will only fire once.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind some code to the `keyup` event:

```
$('#upload-message').keyup(function(){
    //this code fires every time the user releases a key
    $('.step-3').removeClass('error');
    $('.details').removeClass('error');
});
```